# Form.Show() not showing form

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I've a c# project in which a form hides itself after some background task finishes, to be opened on command, but under certain conditions, the call to this.Show() or setting this.Visible to true doesn't make the form reappear! I even had the state of the form's Visible value output to be sure, and the form seems to think it's on screen, but it's nowhere to be seen.

The condition that seems to cause it to break is if I give another window control before the form hides itself. If I let it stay in front while it's working, hide itself, then tell it to come back it always does, even if I change focus after the fact, but I change focus away beforehand, it doesn't reappear, even though form.Show appears to be called.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening? It's such a weird case, especially since the state of form.Visible changes.

```
public partial class testForm : Form {
    private void testForm_Sometrigger(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //some delay. In the actual program, this is thanks to a background worker working.
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //manually change focus to another process/window before this
        this.Hide();
        //I've been adding a wait here, since in practice the form won't be called again right away.
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        //show form again.
        this.Show();
        // this will be true even if the form isn't actually visible
        Console.WriteLine("is visible? "+this.Visible.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Code block added upon request. There isn't much to this bit, just showing and hiding and time passing, really.

Comment: can you provide a minimal, complete example so we could reproduce the problem?

Comment: Show us the code please, and make sure it constitutes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sometimes the form is visible but you can see because it's mínimized or other reason. Hide the form or ensure it's closed. I recomend to use a third class that control what form It shown. Like a semafore. Put a simple Code in the question to be more exactly.

Comment: You can't do `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread without getting some bad behavior.

Comment: if `testForm_Sometrigger` is being called from a non-ui thread you have to marshal the call to the UI thread to make changes to things that affect, you know, the UI.

Comment: @ Scott: Thankfully, Thread.Sleep isn't used in the actual code, but annoyingly the tests using it are somewhat more stable. It just takes the place of time passing or work being done, here.

Comment: @ Sam: The trigger that originally started this issue is a background worker's finished event that causes the hide, and a WndProc override that listens for a certain key combination and calls the method to show the screen again. This is my first time messing with WndProc, so I don't want to entirely rule that out, but the method it's supposed to call always runs, form.Visible toggles, but the form stays hidden. All of this _should_ be going on in the UI thread, far as I can tell, but honestly threading is probably the most likely cause, I just can't work out how.

Comment: Tip: you are allowed to *answer* your own question, when you have found a solution

Comment: @HansKesting Right. It's been a while since I've been here, I suppose. I'll do that and accept the solution once enough time has passed for it to be allowed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the window not appearing probably has something to do with form inactivity and the UI thread not coming back to it, so adding a Form.Activate() after the show call fixed it.

Original question updated with solution.

Comment: If you're unable to update the UI because you're blocking the UI thread, then the solution is to *stop blocking the UI thread*.  Trying to hack your way around it is just going to create *more* problems.

Comment: In this case, after the hide call there's no UI activity in the application until it's called upon by the user and shown—so it's possible it's not just that the form is inactive, but the whole application is, especially since the problem only appears when focus is switched away to another process (like Visual Studio, for example, or msaccess, which is more likely to be open alongside this program). In some cases the window would eventually reappear after a long delay.

Which is to say, I can say with some confidence that this application isn't what's keeping the UI thread from reacting.